# Why `this.setState({num: this.state.num++})` click twice the value do not change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a demo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App1 extends Component {
    
    state = {
        num: 1
    }
  
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>{this.state.num}</h6>
        <button onClick={() => {
            this.setState({num: this.state.num++})  // the state.num do not add
            console.log(this.state.num)
        }}> Cumulative </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

We know in React there have two ways to update the state item,

```
1.this.state.num = value
2.this.setState({num: value})  # DOM will automatic updates
```

so, in my demo, `this.setState({num: this.state.num++})` when I trigger buttons **multi times**( at least twice),  I think the `num` value will add, but the demo do not.

I know there should write like this way `this.setState({num: ++this.state.num})`, but I want to know why the demo do not work.

---

**EDIT-01**

but the this.state.num++, the num should add 1(don't update the DOM), when I click the second time, I think it should change.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App1 extends Component {
    
    state = {
        num: 1
    }
  
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>{this.state.num}</h6>
        <button onClick={() => {

            this.state.num++
            this.setState({num: this.state.num})  
            console.log(this.state.num)
        }}> Cumulative </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this way it will work.

Comment: You shouldn’t be incrementing `this.state.num` directly.  Use `{ num: this.state.num + 1 }`.

Comment: so the `this.state.num++` would not set it value right?

Comment: the post-increment assignment is setting it to its current value, not the incremented value.

Comment: but the `this.state.num++`, the `num` should add 1(don't update the DOM), when I click the second time, I think it should change.

Comment: It assigns the existing value to `num`, then increments `this.state.num`, then runs the `setState` function which sets it back to the (unincremented) value of `num` you passed in.